# 4.25.toFixed(1) == 4.35.toFixed(1) == 4.3 but 2.35.toFixed(1)==2.4

Tags: javascript, floating-point

When the non fractional part is bigger than 4 the fractional part it is truncated to `.3` but when it is smaller than 4 it is rounded to `.4`.

### Examples:

#### 1.nr>4:

```
5.35.toFixed(1) => 5.3
15.35.toFixed(1) => 15.3
131.35.toFixed(1) => 131.3
```

#### 2.nr<4:

```
2.35.toFixed(1) =>2.4
1.35.toFixed(1) =>1.4
```

Is this kind of behaviour normal?

Comment: 8.75.toFixed(1) == 8.8 which is correct

Comment: Right, but the point is that 8 is bigger than 4.

Comment: @Pointy but I was referring to .35 fractional part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the *exact* values you're calling `toFixed` on aren't 1.35 etc... they're the nearest IEEE-754 64-bit representation. In this case, the exact values are:

```
1.350000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
2.350000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
5.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375
15.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375
```

Now look at *those* values and work out what you'd do in terms of rounding to 1 decimal place.

Basically you're falling foul of the fact that these are floating *binary* point values, so the value you express in *decimal* isn't always the value that's actually used. It's just an approximation. In other languages the preferred alternative is to use a type which represents floating *decimal* point values (e.g. `BigDecimal` in Java or `decimal` in C#) but I don't know of anything similar within standard Javascript. You may find some third party libraries though.

Comment: (2.35+0.000000001).toFixed(1) would do the trick

Comment: @EmilCondrea: Well it depends - not if you could reasonably end up with a value which is *legitimately* just a tiny bit less than 2.35, and shouldn't be rounded up.